# Delete everything but TWO patterns

Tags: sed

Is there a way to delete everything but TWO patterns in bash?

I know i can delete everything but pattern with

```
sed '/pattern/!d'
```

but I'm looking for a way delete everything but two patterns... something like this

```
sed '/pattern1 and pattern2/!d'
```

I don't know how to do this.

btw. I'm trying to delete everything but <..> and <..>:

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to delete all lines that don't contain `pattern1` *or* `pattern2`. Use the proper OR for this.

```
$ cat in.txt
foo
bar
baz
qux
$ sed '/foo\|bar/!d' < in.txt
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Better answer to what I had before. You could just use `grep` for this task assuming your patterns are in `in.txt` and your output will be in `out.txt`

```
grep -E -o '(pattern1|pattern2) in.txt > out.txt'
```

`E` is for extended regular expressions and `o` is to show only matching patterns.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `!d` you can use `-n` and the `p` command:

```
sed -n '/pattern1/p; /pattern2/p'
```

Which should also work with seds other than GNU sed...

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with either `awk` or `sed`.

```
$ cat file
foo
bar
baz
qux
$ sed -n '/foo\|bar/p' file
foo
bar
$ awk '/foo|bar/' file
foo
bar
```

The above will print any lines containing `foo` or `bar`. If you wish to be more specific, for instance, only print when `foo` or `bar` are at the start of the line, you can use `^`, which means print only those that start with your pattern.